# Sqlcipher iOS always saying "Password correct"

Tags: ios, sqlite, sqlcipher

I have a problem using sqlcipher for ios.
I have followed this example to create database named "testing.db" :

https://charlesleifer.com/blog/encrypted-sqlite-databases-with-python-and-sqlcipher/

Then I moved to this tutorial to integrate sqlcipher source to my project and configure it :

https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ios-tutorial/

The problem is when I test my code with different password (keys), it always displays to me "Password is correct, or a new database has been initialized" even if I set a wrong filename for my database (always same message).

What can be the error here ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must have made an error.

Comment: just refollowed the exact steps for integration...and have the same result

Comment: What happens if you use the correct file path and an incorrect password?

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher/issues/124 for the resolution:

The database file is not being included with the application when it compiles. Since the file does not exist, SQLCipher creates it for you, accepting any password you provide.